# Elastic search query fail: No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

Here is the mapping. I have a property named `@timestamp`.

```json
{
  "my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date_nanos"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I query like this:

```json
{
   "sort" : {
        "@timestamp" : "desc"
    }
}
```

I got an error: `No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort on`.
I found some solution using `unmapping_type`, but I have definition in the property. Could someone help explain this case? I just started to use elasticsearch. Thanks.

Comment: Are you querying on your specific index `my_index/_search` or on `/_search`, i.e. all indexes?

Comment: @Val Oh, yes. Forget this. `.kibana_1` doesn't has this field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query on your specific index

```
GET my_index/_search
```

And not

```
GET /_search
```

Because otherwise you'll hit all indexes in your cluster and the odds are high that one of them doesn't have a `@timestamp` field.

Comment: This can't be used in the PIT search requests.

Comment: @HariomYadav how is this thread related to PIT?